# execute immediate iNSERT issue for dynamic table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, insert

I am studying about oracle sql

I am trying to create dynamic table
and
i would like to insert some values into dynamic table ( "s" is the variable name)

i was trying to use...

```
 execute immediate 'INSERT INTO t'||tbcounter||'(column1, column2) VALUES (s, s)';
```

however, i am getting error

```
ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword
```

I am guessing there is syntax error..

but i am not really sure the error in the code..

does anyone know the error in the code ?

thanks

EDIT:

I just fixed problem. Inserting should be

```
 sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO t'||tbcounter||' VALUES (:1, :2)';
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING s, s;
```

Comment: You should post you update as an answer.  You are allowed to do this.  Furthermore you should accept it, as this solution is generally better practice that the answer you have accepted.

Comment: sorry, I didn't know how to do it. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
execute immediate 'INSERT INTO t'||tbcounter||' (column1, column2) VALUES (' || s || ' , ' s || ' )'  ;
```

IS tbcounter is table name .

Comment: t+counter like.... if tcounter is 1 then we create t1 table and insert data in variable s

Comment: execute immediate 'INSERT INTO t'||tbcounter||'(column1, column2) VALUES ('||s||', '||s||')'; something like this ?

Comment: s VARCHAR2(200); and using  utl_file.get_line(f,s); to get the line of data from the txt file